# How can I use this timer?

Tags: timer

At my home I have this timer and I am not sure how to use it. Model seems to be TM8IM-24. I have found a company that [sells it](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://www.cefco.co.uk/CEFCO%2520Catalogue%2520pdf%2527s/CEFCO%2520catalogue_Page%2520152.pdf&ei=w3K-UKVq4aDRBcOigZAN&usg=AFQjCNEP9S4OakYYpS_h6ND_vlTVLb2YWA&sig2=oxRNZVLkIRlPc1TdiI80Dg) but cannot find instructions.

Does anyone knows how to use it or where I can find instructions?

[image: TM8IM-24 Timer]
[image: Lateral view]

Comment: You might try contacting the manufacturer, as it appears their [website](http://www.timerm8.com/) is down (under construction).

Comment: Do the tabs pull off, or do they work like a switch?  If they work like a switch, usually pushed out is off, pushed in is on. If the pull off and are all identical, every tab changes the state: on-off-on-off, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you pull the red tabs in or out to have the device turn on or off for a given 15 minute interval. I'm guessing the black arrow is pointing to the current time. The switch on the side is to manually turn it on or off (or perhaps permanently off or on the timer). You'll just need to test it to see if the tabs being in or out correspond to on vs off. And to know about the switch on the side, try turning it off and see if the timer moves after 30 minutes.

To adjust the current time, you can turn the dial clockwise, but not counter clockwise.

Comment: Thanks. My main doubt is if I have to put the red tabs in or out. The lateral switch has three positions. I guess they are alwasy ON, ON depending on tabs and OFF

Comment: @cad, I think you have the side switch properly identified. For the tabs, you'll just have to test them. From the current settings of the tabs, that doesn't look like it's used for lighting. Is it hooked up to a water pump for a pool or pond?

Comment: It is used for water heater, so testing is hard as if I have hot water maybe because is being heated now or it has been recently. But you gave me an idea as I will try a multimeter in heater to see when I have current and when not...

Comment: @cad, A water heater? Wow, that's different. If you have the DIY bug, I'd suggest getting a non-contact voltage tester, which is much safer for working around potentially live wiring.

Answer (score 1):

It works on the principle of:

ON = tab pushed out away from centre (15 minutes per tab)

OFF = tab pushed in towards centre

see https://youtu.be/USSC3Y9rKnQ

The slider switch is:

DOWN (T setting) - tab timers are used

UP (ON setting) - permanently on

MIDDLE - permanently off

Comment: I have the same timer and use it successfully